# Can I print business cards with the same information as in Outlook vcf file?

Tags: business-cards

I work at a US based Investment Bank and I want business card for myself with employer info (such as name, logo, address of office, my designation and department primarily). However, the bank does not issue the cards itself, but I see an electronic business card in .vcf format on Microsoft Outlook used within the bank. So, can I use the information included in the vcf file to print business cards for myself?

Comment: You should ask your manager.

Comment: Usually you should ask your company for permission, if you want to use their logo. The vcf file contains only the data (address, phone, email, etc.), so I’m not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can print private business cards putting on there whatever you want.

Business cards that list you employer's name and use employer's phone, e-mail, address and/or logo must follow the companies policies and templates.